# Update to xcode 7.3 is not working

Tags: xcode

Is someone else having problems to update xcode 7.2 to 7.3?
Firstly there is no update option in App Store. I found a link at [App Store xcode 7.3](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12), this link will open your app store on the xcode page, after I press update, a loading spinner appears but after 2 hours of waiting nothing has happened [image] Is there another way to update xcode?

---

Edit: There is no option update xcode in App Store
[image]

Comment: I've always had weird issues when updating Xcode. Often it will go through the whole update process and then the App Store still says there is an update available. Anyway, try restarting the App Store and opening the App Store directly, going to your `Updates` tab at the top, and updating Xcode from there.

Comment: I tried restart before, but update button wont show up. Even after i update the system.

Comment: Are you running OS X 10.11 or later? It's required to install Xcode 7.3.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

xcode 7.3 is not supported in OS lower than 10.11, You need to upgrade your OS to OS X 10.11 or later (El Capitan) and try to upgrade the xcode to 7.3

Comment: it would be nice for them to tell you that... FAIL

Answer (score 7):

You can download Xcode yourself from https://developer.apple.com/downloads (an Apple Developer account required).

This is what you should see (I filtered the available downloads by typing "Xcode"):

[image]

Comment: ty, but about the update button, there is no solution?

Comment: In my experience it doesn't work very well for Xcode either, so I usually just download and install the new versions myself. I think the App Store experience is just not optimized for apps as large as Xcode (version 7.3 is almost 5GB).

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but when I go to the link provided, then hit Download, I go to a page that says "View in App Store." Going there, the only available option I can see is "Update," which is what everyone seems to be complaining about. Is there a way out of the Catch 22?

Comment: @rattletrap99 hmm, that's odd. You should see a big list of things to download, among them the current and previous version of Xcode. I updated my answer with a picture. Here's the direct link to the Xcode 7.3 installer: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3/Xcode_7.3.dmg

Comment: Thx. Having trouble getting in the door. Will report back when I've got that straightened out...

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue right now. Xcode wont update, stuck on loading icon.

Comment: @rattletrap99.  There is an issue with login redirect for developer.apple.com.  Once you logged in, just click on a link in this post and you will see the screen described here

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I was trying to update to **Xcode 8.1** with **Waiting..** status on AppStore under Xcode icon. What I has done to fix this is:

1) Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/ 
[image]

2) Press **Lunch Application**
[image]

And when it opens on AppStore, it will refresh the status from **Waiting..** to **Downloading...**